# Returning a concatenated string from a functions' properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function

I'm a total JS beginner. Here is the JsBin [link](https://jsbin.com/ruyibu/20/edit?js,output) `formLetter` test should be passing.

### TL;DR

This:

```
var formLetter = function(recipient, msg, sender) {
  return "Hello " + recipient + ",\n" + "\n" + msg + "\n" + "\nSincerely," + "\n" + sender
  };
 console.log(formLetter("Hermione", "Luna","How are you?"));
```

Should return:

```
"Hello Hermione,

 How are you?

 Sincerely,
 Luna"
```

But instead I get this:

```
"Hello [object Object],

 undefined

 Sincerely,
 undefined"
```

### Edit

Sorry for the confusion. I'm working on different problems inside one JsBin. This is the correct JsBin with the **isolated** [code](https://jsbin.com/kiyimuc/edit?js,console).

Comment: Well, that tells you that `recipient` is an object, not a string, and either `msg` and `sender` aren't given in the call to `formLetter` at all, or they're given but have the value `undefined`. You haven't shown that call in your question, so we really can't help. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are only getting one object passed into the function call.  This object contains the information you need in lieu of the named arugments you have provided.

The first argument, `recipient` being `[object Object]` tells you that it's an object.  `undefined` means that nothing was passed in their place.  This signifies the common pattern of a config or param object being passed to the function call.  Because of this, what you have as named arguments should really be property look ups on the object provided as the first argument.

Your function definition should look more like:

```
    var formLetter = function (letter) {
        // do something with letter
    };
```

Inside of that function call, you may then hit the properties of the letter object to see if they contain what you need,  Doing `console.log` debugging in dev tools will help track it down.

Comment: Thanks, that clarified some questions I had. This and @Martin Johansson's message.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
var formLetter = function(recipient, msg, sender) {
  return "Hello " + recipient + ",\n" + "\n" + msg + "\n" + "\nSincerely," + "\n" + sender
};
```

in your example needs one semicolon after "sender", like:

```
var formLetter = function(recipient, msg, sender) {
  return "Hello " + recipient + ",\n" + "\n" + msg + "\n" + "\nSincerely," + "\n" + sender;
};
```

Your undefined is related to the use of anidated `console.log`.

You do:

```
console.log(longMessage.formLetter("Hermione", "Luna","How are you?"));
```

and (in the JsBin) you have also:

```
var longMessage = {
  formLetter: function(recipient, sender, msg) {
    console.log("Hello " + recipient + ",\n" + "\n" + msg + "\n" + "\nSincerely," + "\n" + sender);
  }
};
```

In the example of your question you have them corrected.

Double check the code you post, please.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your test in jsbin, I noticed that in your `assert.deepEqual()` method you run `formLetter(letter)` and compares it to the concatenated string you created. 
The problem is that `formLetter()` expects three string values and you send it an object (letter). That's why you get [Object object] in the first location and undefined in the others.

You should run `formLetter(letter.recipient, letter.msg, letter.sender)` in your assert and it should work properly.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me the hint on how to work with my `letter` object